# React-native - How to open image from file path in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, opencv, react-native

### Question

I have an app functionality that checks if the taken photo is blurred. Now I have followed this tutorial: [Tutorial](https://brainhub.eu/blog/opencv-react-native-image-processing/)

This tutorial takes a base64 representation of the image and passes it to native function.

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(checkForBlurryImage:(NSString *)imageAsBase64 callback:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback){...}
```

But as you know, base64 for large images is quite slow. What I would like to do is to pass the file path where the image is saved and then open that image in `Objectve-C`. I presume, that this way the processing time will be faster with significantly less overhead.

I have tried to implement this the following way:

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(checkForBlurryImage2:(NSString *)imagePath callback: (RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback){

  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
  ...
 }
```

I have used the native api function `UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile`that reads the image from file system.

### Problem

The problem is that, when the upper function return `nil`. In documentation it states, that `nil` is returned when the path is incorrect or the  image can't be opened.

The path that I usually get from the camera looks like this:

> file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/FD0CBDBA-8B59-4618-B1A8-006FA4D33901/Library/Caches/Camera/804062B5-896F-4AAF-A35F-4F10A648B916.jpg

What is the correct way to open the image from file path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/FD0CBDBA-8B59-4618-B1A8-006FA4D33901/Library/Caches/Camera/804062B5-896F-4AAF-A35F-4F10A648B916.jpg` is a file URL in a string, not a file path.

To get the file path from the file URL string, create a URL object from the URL string, then get the path of the URL.

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(checkForBlurryImage2:(NSString *)URLString callback: (RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback){
    NSURL* URL = [NSURL URLWithString:URLString];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:URL.path];
    ...
}
```